# Change properties of programmatically created UIButton in a different IBAction

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have one method that creates a number of `UIButton` instances programmatically and positions them in the view. Another `IBAction` needs to change the background colour of one of these `UIButton` when fired however when I try to action it, it tells me that the Property not found on object of type `UIView *`

The button is created using:

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[view addSubview:button];
```

When I try to access it from the other IBAction like:

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

It fails with the error noted above.

Any help is much appreciated. I saw another answer which suggested to create an array as an `IBOutlet` and access it that way but I'm wondering if there's another way.

Thanks!

Comment: We will need more code than that. This doesn't provide any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare this `button` in globally and identify each button in `tag`, just like or assume this

```
 UIButton * button, *button2; // declare in your view controller.h

 - (IBAction)butaction:(id)sender;    //this is your color change method;
```

in your view controller.m   wherever u add this button

```
 button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 button.tag=10;   //this is important
 [self.view addSubview:button];

  button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  button1.tag=20;   //this is important
 [self.view addSubview:button1];


  //here ur color change method

     - (IBAction) butaction:(UIButton*)sender {


     switch (sender.tag)
      {
       case 10:
         [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

       break;

        case 20:
            [button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
          break;

       default:
        break;

           }
        }
```

Comment: this is not a perfect answer, customize ur self

Comment: Thanks Anbu, I declared the UIButtons in my .h file and synthesised them in the .m file and now they're available everywhere for actions.

Comment: its is iddentiy with tag on evey action

Comment: tanx bro, will u need any assistance ask me

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it may be helpful

```
for (int index=1; index<=5; index++) {
    UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClickedFunction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag= index;
    [view addSubview:button];
};
```

implement this in IBAction

```
 -(IBAction)ButtonClickedFunction:(UIButton *)button{
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  }
```

Note: In this I have created 5 buttons but not set  frame. Please set frame according to your requirements. 
Thanks